# Get the choice field options for SPO using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, choice-field

I need to get all the choice options on a SharePoint Online List with PowerShell. I can find many sample scripts for on-premise SharePoint but I cannot convert them successfully in SharePoint Online. Could you please advise which PS module and script I can get the choices option for SPO?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using PnP PowerShell. Here are some resources that will help you get started.

[PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/index.html)

[Installing PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html)

[Connecting with PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/connecting.html)

I have a site that has a list named **Choices Test**. This list has a choice column named **Color** with three choices: Red, Green, and Blue. I can use PnP PowerShell to get those choice values from the column.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://robwindsortest986.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo
$field = Get-PnPField -List "Choices Test" -Identity "Color"
[xml]$schemaXml = $field.SchemaXml
$schemaXml.Field.CHOICES
```

[image: PowerShell screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Rob's answer, the values can also be extracted from the TypedObject property:

```
$column = Get-PnPField -List $list_name -Identity "TestChoice"
$column.TypedObject.Choices # these are the field choices
```